# Makefile conditional rules execution

Tags: makefile

I have a requirement to run particular rules depending upon the existence of an environment variable.

```
test1:
    -echo "test1"

test2:
    -echo "test2"

run:
    -echo "Running"
```

So my requirement is if I do `make run`, then both the rules `test1` and `test2` should execute IF environment variable say `RUN_ONLY_TEST1` is NOT set on shell. However if this environment variable is set, then only rule `test1` should execute.

Can some one please help me if this is feasible. This is just a sample example and I have a lot of commands in my original makefile , so putting if/else in run target would require a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you yourself imply `RUN_ONLY_TEST1` is another way of saying `RUN_NOT_TEST2345`.  I.e. you have created a negative problem statement, which is a bit hard to implement, since it means lots of exclusions.

I would go for a positive approach, the easiest being a list of tests to run:

```
TESTS = 1 2            # Can override this on command line or environment
```

In [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) you could then write your last rule simply as:

```
run: test$(TESTS)
```

In gmake it would be just a little harder:

```
run: $(addprefix test,$(TESTS))
```

The "running" part is then wrong, because all prerequisites have been built (i.e.tests have run) by the time you get to this rule.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will try this in my main project.